# Ajuda com função recursiva no Python

Tags: funções, recursão, fatorial

Sou iniciante com muita dificuldade em entender a função recursiva, sei que é uma função que chama à ela mesma, porém não consigo faze-la funcionar a contento, no exercício praticado em aula, foi dado o exercício...

"Faça uma função que receba um número e calcule seu fatorial."

O que fiz foi a função abaixo...

```py
def fatorial():
              num = int(input('Insira um número: '))
              contador = 0
              fatorial = 1
              while contador < num:
                            contador += 1
                            fatorial = fatorial * contador
              print('O fatorial de', num, 'é', fatorial)
fatorial()
```

A função está funcionando sem problemas, agora preciso compreender como fazer a função recursiva neste mesmo exercício feito anteriormente, onde pede...

"Repita o exercício anterior usando recursão, ou seja, uma função que chame ela mesma, lembrando que 3! = 3*2!, que 2! = 2*1!, que 1! = 1*0! e que 0! = 1."

Seria a função abaixo considerada recursiva ?

```py
def fatorial(x):

              if x == 1:
                            return 1
              elif x==0:
                            return 1
              else:
                            return x * fatorial(x-1)
while True:
              x = int(input("Fatorial de: "))
              print("Fatorial do número escolhido é: ",fatorial(x) )
              fatorial(x)
```

Gostaria de saber também se, a função recursiva deve ter 1 única função ou pode ter 2 funções, bem como eu faria inserções no primeiro escopo para ambos funcionar se for o caso ou se devo utilizar somente 1 escopo, se seria o segundo o mais indicado ?

Quem puder me ajudar com a dúvida, agradeço !

Comment: Sim, a função `fatorial` é recursiva porque chama a si mesma (sugiro que leia todos os links que estão [no box azul desta pergunta](/q/438762/112052)). "*a função recursiva deve ter 1 única função ou pode ter 2 funções, bem como eu faria inserções no primeiro escopo para ambos funcionar se for o caso ou se devo utilizar somente 1 escopo, se seria o segundo o mais indicado*" - não entendi o que quer dizer, talvez esteja usando os termos errados para descrever determinadas coisas ou situações, pois ficou confuso.

Comment: Obrigado...provavelmente errei nos termos mesmo por ser um mero novato no python. Pensa que a última vez que programei algo, foi na época do extinto basic...rs

Answer (score 0):

Olá, a versão recursiva da função fatorial parece-me bem, só uma dica: o caso do x==1 e x==0 é o mesmo (return 1) pelo que não precisa de separar esses casos em dois ifs diferentes:

```
def fatorial(x):
    if x<2:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fatorial(x-1)
```

e sim, se necessário uma função recursiva pode chamar outras funções

Comment: Obrigado...na verdade coloquei o elif, pois ao digitar 0 (zero) e buscar seu fatorial (1), a instrução terminava. Desse jeito eu a deixei operando sem fim para inserção de números durante o exercício.